# Select rows for the first n distinct elements (two or more columns)

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following data set, I want to select the rows (all columns) comprised between the first one and the last of the result of selecting 'n' distinct on col1 and col2.

```
pkey | col1 | col2 | day | Other columns...
1    | a    | 1    | 1   |
2    | b    | 2    | 1   |
3    | b    | 2    | 1   |
4    | c    | 3    | 1   |
5    | c    | 4    | 1   |
6    | a    | 5    | 2   |
7    | a    | 5    | 2   |
8    | b    | 6    | 2   |
9    | c    | 7    | 2   |
10   | c    | 8    | 2   |
```

For n = 5, the result must be:

```
pkey | col1 | col2 | day | Other columns...
1    | a    | 1    | 1   |
2    | b    | 2    | 1   |
3    | b    | 2    | 1   |
4    | c    | 3    | 1   |
5    | c    | 4    | 1   |
6    | a    | 5    | 2   |
7    | a    | 5    | 2   |
```

[image]

I am trying by using `SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM sampletable` as a base but then I have no access to the other columns. How could this be achieved?

**Edit:**

Changed description to be more clear regarding what I want
Changed col2 of rows 6 and 7 from 1 to 5 to be closer to my real data.

Comment: Why does your result set have two rows where `col1` = b and  `col2` = 2, and another two rows where `col1` = a and `col2` = 1?  I thought you wanted rows only where those are distinct?

Comment: It looks like `col1` and `col2` will always be distinct, as one stores a `char` and the other one an `int`. Also why would `n=5` return 7 rows? Isn't it supposed to return just 5? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry, I was not fully clear on what I want. I want to select all rows which are comprised between the first and the one pointed by the count of n two-column distinct.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM sampletable AS a
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM sampletable LIMIT 5) AS b
ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2
```

Comment: would this not give `col1` and `col2` in the result set twice?  Should you not select `a.*` rather than `*`?

Comment: Yes ,col1/col2 combination will possibly occur more than once. As you shown in your desired results with the b-2 combination. Yes a.* is prefered, i will edit.

Comment: The `TOP n` syntax doesn't work in MySQL. You want `SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM sampletable LIMIT 5` as the subquery.

Comment: @MattRaines ha! I could swear i read t-sql. Thank you Matt, edited acordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.* from sampletable a inner join (
    SELECT  MIN(pkey) as pkey FROM sampletable GROUP BY col1,col2 limit 5) b on a.pkey = b.pkey
```

Use this query.

Comment: pkey would always be distinctive. This query selects all records.

Comment: I have put limit 5 at the end of nested query so it should select only 5 records

Comment: Thanks, the result must contain 7 rows. I updated my description of the problem hoping to be more clear.

Comment: Updated my query according to your modified description. Please check

Answer (score -1):

Another different way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(col1, col2)) AS fgroup, pkey, day... FROM [table] GROUP BY fgroup LIMIT [LIMIT]
```

Replace [table] by your table name.

Replace [limit] by the desired limit.

Replace the "..." by all the extra fields that you want to list.

Comment: This would cause an incorrect syntax. You are not concatenating in the group by and that column does not exists.

Comment: It is an example, you have to replace "..." by your columns and [table] and [LIMIT] by the table name and the desired limit. It works because I tested it, and this way is more optimal than use an inner join (Add the "explain" command in front of the query to test that)

Comment: Juan, you still not observing the syntax error in the group by, column names or not, this will not run, you need to contact in the group by too. even then it would not produce the desire results. Give it a try, check for yourself.